# working around maven error: Project 'XYZ' is duplicated in the reactor

Tags: maven-2

I'm creating a multi-module project that builds many other, related projects.  Some of these projects are multi-module projects as well, and in some cases they build the same sub-project.  Maven yells at me, but this is intentional and I'd like it to build anyway.

Has anyone worked around this?
Thanks.

Comment: the error occurring project must be in single hierarchy. For me, it was referred from multiple modules.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you should do that.
(You could try defining a profile - let say a complete-build profile, where you make sure that every module is compiled just once, an another profile that adds the additional modules when you do a sub-build.)

But you better go the maven way - every project should include as modules only directories from its own directory, e.g. only direct children.

Maven has some non-written implicit assumptions like - always inherit submodules, from the pom in the parent directory, e.g. the inheritance tree must match your directory tree, otherwise some plugins won't work, e.g. release plugin, or some report plugins.

The short answer is - in maven you cannot have a module twice in your project hierarchy/tree.

There are a lot of wrong ways in maven, therefore one must stick to something that is known to work - like pom hierarchy == directory structure.

Comment: `in maven you cannot have a module twice in your project hierarchy/tree` is what I've been looking for. I think it's silly for Maven to not allow this and be able to figure it out though.

Answer (score 14):

This happen when you have a structure like this:

```
+-- root-project-A
    `-- pom.xml
    +-- module-A
    |   `-- pom.xml
    +-- module-B
    |   `-- pom.xml
    +-- root-project-B
        `-- pom.xml
        +-- module-C
            `-- pom.xml
```

And configure yours modules like this:

```
|-- root-project-A
    `-- pom.xml
        <modules>
         <module>module-A</module>
         <module>module-B</module>
         <module>root-project-B</module> <!-- Error: project A reference project B -->
         <module>root-project-B/module-C</module> <!-- Error: project A reference project B -->
        </modules>

|-- root-project-B
    `-- pom.xml
        <modules>
         <module>module-C</module>
        </modules>
```

The project A cannot reference the project B, because B doesn't reference A as parent. The package must be independent.

Answer (score 12):

For me `<artifactId>` was same for 2 different module in their pom and that caused this error.
Once changed, it worked fine .

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Also worked for me. Was a little unobvious mistake, but it was there. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In my case IntelliJ put `<module>parentModule/XYZ</module>` in parent parent module pom.xml

So check with Find All (*CTRL+SHIFT+F*) 'XYZ' for eventual mistakes

Comment: Yup. This was it.

Comment: This !!!! Always check the immediate Parent's pom file.

Answer (score 1):

check your poms files,it seems it has been added to more than one module `<modules>XYZ</modules>`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the "same sub-project" you might build from several projects is a dependency for all those projects. Move it up to a nice high level in your directory tree, and declare it as a dependency in all the project poms that need it. It will be built by the first project that you build that needs it, and the rest will see that you've "been there, done that" and skip it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to build an Eclipse RCP using Tycho.

I discovered the error was happening because my .product and my main feature had the same id (namely, mjVoices).

I changed them to mjVoicesProduct and mjVoicesFeature, respectively.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried one of these command-line options?

```
-fae,--fail-at-end            Only fail the build afterwards; allow all
                              non-impacted builds to continue
-fn,--fail-never              NEVER fail the build, regardless of project
                              result
```

Comment: No this is bad. I honestly don't even know if it still allows the build to work when the poms have a setup issue, but it doesn't matter even if it did. Even if it did get the build to succeed, now you're looking at a build 'succeeding' when there are compilation failures, for example, among dozens of other problems this will hide.