Facing error in POM.XML Resolve Error in Pom.xml related to Project 'com.newdemo.service:microservice-new:0.0.1-SNAPHOT' is duplicated in the reactor
Facing error in POM.XML Resolve Error in Pom.xml related to Project 'com.newdemo.service:microservice-new:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' is duplicated in the reactor .
The error message indicates that the project com.newdemo.service:microservice-new:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is duplicated in the Maven reactor. This typically occurs when Maven encounters the same project multiple times within its build process
# Error - [ERROR] [ERROR] Project 'com.newdemo.service:microservice-new:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' is duplicated in the reactor @  [ERROR] Project 'com.newdemo.service:microservice-new:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' is duplicated in the reactor -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DuplicateProjectException
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.newdemo.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservice-new</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>microservice-new</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>product-service</module>
        <module>order-service</module>
        <module>inventory-service</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.7</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588429/working-around-maven-error-project-xyz-is-duplicated-in-the-reactor
